# GODOT. Tween transition parallel to 2 other chained transitions

Tags: animation, transition, godot, gdscript, tween

im trying to tween something like this:
[Two consecutive animations parallel to another animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6nLL.png)
I tried to achieve this result in that way, but the last animation does not play, the object immediately returns to its original size, as it should, but without animation. Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

```
var tween = get_tree().create_tween()
tween.set_parallel()

tween.tween_property($Sprite, "global_position", Vector2(1,1), 1)
tween.tween_property($Sprite, "scale", Vector2(1.5,1.5), 0.5)
tween.tween_property($Sprite, "scale", Vector2(1,1), 0.5).set_delay(0.5)

tween.play()
```

Thanks in advance for your help

tried to type `tween.chain().tween_property($Sprite, "scale", Vector2(1,1), 0.5)` but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your tweens all operate from their initial state.  This is a bit confusing because the documentation refers to this as their "current" state - but it means current relative to the state when the tween was created.  So, with the scaling tweens:

- The first one scales from Vector2(1,1) to Vector2(1.5, 1.5)
- The second one scales from Vector2(1,1) to Vector2(1,1)

This is because the scale when the tween is started is Vector2(1,1) - it doesn't scale from the size that it has been modified to but from the size it was initially.  I hope that makes sense.

To fix this, you need to tell it what size to scale from using the `.from()` function.  See below:

```
var tween = get_tree().create_tween()
tween.set_parallel()

tween.tween_property($Sprite, "global_position", Vector2(1,1), 1)
tween.tween_property($Sprite, "scale", Vector2(1.5,1.5), 0.5)
tween.tween_property($Sprite, "scale", Vector2(1,1), 0.5).set_delay(0.5).from(Vector2(1.5, 1.5))

tween.play()
```